# Is there a way to enable the Touchables on an iOS simulator via the CLI in react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

In react-native debug mode you can enable the debug menu, select "Show Inspector" > Touchables. Then the iOS simulator shows the Touchable areas.

Is there a way to enable this via the CLI? I'd like to have this enabled as a default to make engineers aware of the touchables for accessibility reasons.

I've tried:

`xcrun simctl io booted setenv DEBUG_VIEWS 1` and `xcrun simctl io booted execute 'defaults write com.apple.springboard ShowApplicationTouchRegions -bool YES && killall -HUP SpringBoard'`

But this keeps outputting

```
Set up a device IO operation.
Usage: simctl io <device> <operation> <arguments>
```